# Customizing jquery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using tab widget of jQuery UI. I want to change the `color` of active tab to `yellow` by using `ui-tabs-active` class as mentioned [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/) in API docs

But despite of doing following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-tabs-active
    {
      background-color:yellow;
    }
</style>
```

Its color does not change.
Here is the code at [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/iXur/19/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be a little more direct with your CSS. Also you need to remove the default image that resides there

```
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
      background-image: none;
      background-color:green;
    }
```

DEMO http://jsbin.com/iXur/25/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active
{
    background: green;
}
```

the [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/iXur/22/)

Answer (score 1):

change color on ui css file

open css file search about

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { margin-bottom: -1px; padding-bottom: 1px;}
```

change

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { margin-bottom: -1px; padding-bottom: 1px;  background-color:yellow;}
```