# Style control in jQuery tabs UI

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the jQuery UI tabs.

How do I specify a colour to the tab button and text when it's selected and in normal state?

I tried this. But did not work.

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-selected {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active
{
    background: yellow;
}
```

**OR**

change color on ui css file

open css file search about

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { margin-bottom: -1px; padding-bottom: 1px;}
```

change

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { margin-bottom: -1px; padding-bottom: 1px;  background-color:yellow;}
```

ref link:

[Customizing jquery UI tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451846/customizing-jquery-ui-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited {
color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
text-decoration: none;
background: #fc0;
color: #693;
}
```

in this case I have used a yellow bg and green text so you can easily see it. Obviously you can change more things, it's up to you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am reading your question correctly, but couldn't you make a "tabs" div and then style it with css in a separate document or even modify it with getElementById(tabs)?

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-3">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
<div id="fragment-1">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh     euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
<div id="fragment-2">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
<div id="fragment-3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
</div>
```